# If this text is contained within an H1, do something to ONLY that h1, not the others

Tags: jquery, select, filter, element, contains

```
$('h1').hover(function(){
  if ($('h1:contains("three")')) {
    $(this).css({'color':'#09f'})
  }

    //$('h1').text().filter('three').css( 'color', '#09f' );
})
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to select only the element that contains the text. Right now, the code above will turn ever h1's color to `#09f` when that element's hovered, it should only turn the matching h1's color to `#09f`.

I'm trying to figure this out for a different use case.
Does anyone know the best method for doing something to ONLY the matching element? 
would it be .filter()? :contains()? .contains()? .is()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.is()` directly:

```
$('h1').hover(function() {
    if($(this).is(':contains("three")')) {
        $(this).css('color', '#09f')
    }

    // $('h1').text().filter('three').css( 'color', '#09f' );
})
```

Comment: My read of the `.contains()` spec [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) is that it only takes DOM elements, not text.  Are you aware of a different `.contains()` method?

Comment: @jfriend00: Sorry, changed to `.is()` now.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `:contains` on your `h1` selector:

```
$('h1:contains("three")').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#09f');
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRTv2/).

Note: since there's no out handler provided to `hover()` the css color stays, but you can fix that with a [second argument to `hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98a4x/2/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this that will only look for the text "three" in the h1 that is being hovered over and change only that h1's color:

```
$('h1').hover(function(){
  if ($(':contains("three")', this).length) {
    $(this).css({'color':'#09f'})
  }
})
```